# Printed .txt file showing values as "num" instead of values

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a bit of a complicated dataframe where each row is a list and each column represents a different variable, as shown in the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FeH4.png

I want to print a .txt file of the information surrounding a specific variable using the following code.

```
#LOAD THE DATA IN
library(raveio)
base :: setwd("path")
filenames <- base::list.files(
  path = ("path"), # Insert your relevant filepath here
  recursive = TRUE,
  pattern = "*.mat"
)
#CONVERT DATA TO LIST
mylist <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read_mat(x))

#CONVERT LIST TO DATAFRAME
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- map_dfr(mylist, ~as.data.frame(t(.)))

#WRITE DATA TO .txt FILE
sink("mydata.txt")
print(mydata$stim)
sink()
```

However, using this code results in the .txt file shown in the following link being generated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggYTj.png

I would like the values associated with the variables such as rtStart to be displayed instead of just showing "numeric," but I'm not sure how to go about this. It works perfectly with the "p" variable, but not for "stim." I've tried unnesting and using the unlist function, but to no avail.

For example, I would want the output file to look something like this:

```
001
rtStart 8867
rtEnd 90382
Category 1
...
```

and so on for every subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understood your request so I might be way of the mark, but if you want to just turn the lists in your initial dataframe (which is called "filenames" i think?) to text I would do :

```
df <- filenames %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~sapply(.,paste0, collpase = ",")))
write.table(df, "mydata.txt")
```

Of course if you only one variable (time, p or stim) just select it first before mutating.
Hope it helps

Comment: Oof I'm so sorry for the messy post- I overworked myself on the problem and was pretty much brain dead by the time I decided to ask for help. I have edited it for clarity and a better example of what's needed. Thank you so much for your help. I tried this and it's giving my the error:  unimplemented type list in EncodeElement. I tried adding the is.character argument, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Okay I actually got it to work by using the sink method rather than the write.table method. Thank you so much! This helped a lot.